Enketo API v2 Authentication Error in iframe - KoboToolbox Form Submission
I'm experiencing an authentication error when submitting an Enketo form (from KoboToolbox) embedded in an iframe using API v2. Here are the details:
Problem:
When submitting an Enketo form embedded in an iframe using API v2, I receive an authentication error from the Enketo server, despite including authentication in the header.
I expected the form to submit the edited answers successfully.
Environment:

API Version: v2
Implementation: Form embedded in iframe
Browser: MS Edge
Enketo/KoboToolbox Version: v2

Error Message:
Inspector shows:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
controller-webform.js:456  submission failed Object
What I've Tried:
Verified the authentication header is correctly formatted.
Tested API v1, which works fine on another instance.
Checked for potential CORS issues.
Questions:
Are there known issues with API v2 authentication in iframes?
Are there specific configuration requirements for API v2 that differ from v1?
Could this be related to CORS or iframe security restrictions?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Tags: enketo, kobotoolbox, javascript, iframe, api-authentication
